# Storing images with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip

I've created a RoR application, and I've got everything set up except for storing photos.  I was wondering how I would accomplish this?

I've heard that Amazon S3 is the way to go and there is a nice gem called paperclip that works great with S3, however paperclip is meant for SQL based DB systems and I'm using MongoDB.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm tackling the exact same problem. S3 easy and straight forward. In the throws of coding now so can't attest to reliability from Rails side but my research led me to Carrierwave https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave over Paperclip. There's a Railscast (Episode #253) to help get you started.